# Why is the while loop not printing?

Tags: java, logic

Trying to print this pattern

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
```

the for and the while loop is somehow not working in the right manner.
Is there any problem with the logic?

```
       public class Test {

           public static void main(String args[]) {
             for (int i = 1; i >= 4; i++) {
               for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                 while (i + j >= 5 && (Math.abs(j - i)) <= 3) {
                   System.out.print("*");
                 }
                 System.out.print(" ");
               }
              System.out.println();
           }

       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first for loop is incorrect:

```
for(int i=1;i>=4;i++)
```

This code says, set `i` to 1, while `i` is greater than or equal to four, increment `i`. Since `i` is 1, the condition never passes.

Btw using an IDE will help you spot errors like this, for example here's what intellij has to say about this piece of code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print center triangle pattern as you mentioned in your question.

Here is the sample program which does print the same.

```
public class TestCenterTriangle {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      printCenterTriangle(4);
   }

   private static void printCenterTriangle(int row) {
       for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
           for (int space = 1; space <= (row - i); space++) {
               System.out.print(" ");
           }

           for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
               System.out.print("*");
           }

           for (int k = (i - 1); k >= 1; k--) {
               System.out.print("*");
           }

           System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Comment: public class TestCenterTriangle() its constructor not class.

Comment: Thanks Prateek !! It was typo mistake. Now fixed that.

Comment: downvoters, may I know the reason to downvote please ?

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class Test{

 public static void main(String args[]){

  int n =15;
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i+=2){
  for(int k=n-i;k>=0;k--)
   System.out.print(" "); 
   for( int j=1;j<=i+1;j++){
    System.out.print("* ");   
   }
    System.out.println();
    }
  }
 }
```

Follow this approach. You can get your output  :-

```
            * 
          * * * 
        * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

---